# Java Simple Date Format Time Issues

Tags: java, datetime

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d = cal.getTime();
System.out.println("Current Time is:"+d);
System.out.println("Time value using kk:" + sdf1.format(d));
System.out.println("Time Value using HH:" + sdf2.format(d));

Result:
Current Time is: Wed Sep 25 00:55:20 IST 2013
Time value using kk : 2013-09-25 24:55:20
Time value using HH : 2013-09-25 00:55:20
```

Can anyone tell why this behavior changes in the time, when using kk and HH.

and also kk gives 24:55:20, is this be useful any where. To my knowledge, there is only 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 is the time range.

Is there any beyond this range, if so where is the place "kk" will be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why there *should* be an error. `k` is [documentedin `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as a field for:

> Hour in day (1-24)

That explains why you get 24 for midnight instead of 00, too. If you don't *want* values between 01 and 24, don't use `kk` in your format string! I can't remember the last time I wanted to use something like that, but presumably it's used in some cases (particularly for values which are always "on the hour" so you get 24:00 instead of 00:00).

Always consult the docs for what format strings mean.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read the java document, but don't know where to apply this case. "on the hour" so you get 24:00 instead of 00:00. can you explain this some more details. so that i can understand better

Comment: @user2813855: In some cases you might want to represent the "end of a day" as 24:00. For example, you might have an event running from 08:00 to 24:00, which is possibly clearer than 08:00 to 00:00. It's pretty rare, but I would just not worry yourself with format fields that you don't personally find useful.

Answer (score 3):

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)...

> k - Hour in day (1-24)
>   H - Hour in day (0-23)

**Updated**

As for why this would be need/supported...There are any number of reasons, some which might be...

- Providing support for external systems.  This makes it possible to parse date/time strings from a variety of sources, providing the API with the flexibility to adapt to the needs of the developer.
- I don't know about you, but my alarm clock works in 1-24 (1-12) hour mode ;)

I would suggest the intention was to try and meet as many of the possible formats that the API may encounter/require without attempting to limit the developer or require us to have to write our own API's.

I don't know about you, but I have lots of other things I need to do ;)

Comment: Thanks, I got that document. But i need the place where this k - Hour in day (1-24) can be useful .

Comment: It would depend.  Some locals may require the time in 1-24 hour format as opposed to 0-23.  It would the same reason why some would need it in 0-11 or 1-12

Comment: @user2813855 You also have to remember, you may need to deal with date/time formats from other systems, not just Java, so while we may not see a use for, some other systems have chosen to use 1-24 as there hourly format...

Comment: @user2813855 I don't know about you, but my alarm clock works in 1-24 (1-12) mode...

Answer (score 3):

This is documented in the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs:

> `H`   Hour in day (0-23)
>   `k`   Hour in day (1-24)
>   `K`   Hour in am/pm (0-11)
>   `h`   Hour in am/pm (1-12)

So, you have 4 different formats for hours. I guess addition of `k` and `h` was a mistake. They really don't make any sense, and almost never needed.

Use `H` for 24-hour formats, and `K` for 12-hour format.

Answer (score 1):

[Kian Fatt, Ting] Buddy the difference is that if you use capital `H is zero to 23 (0-23)`, but if you use small letter `k is one to 24 (1-24)`. The only difference is this and both is right in showing time. You can look at the java documentation link I have provided below.

Souce:[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: [Kian Fatt, Ting] Hope that my answer brings clarity to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can don't use dates and calendar... it's easy to do mistakes with this classes.

jodatime it's a better solution

Comment: Thanks for the info. I like to live within the Java API, Not going for any 3rd party API. So only.